# Creating a flag variable in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a gender variable in the old dataset from a week ago and a gender variable in the current dataset. I have created old and new versions of these variables and combined them into a table called joined.

My goal is to create a flag that will show if there are differences between the old and the new gender variable +- 100. I'd like to know if there is drops.

The gender variable is categorical (categories are: female, male, unknown).

Is there a way for me to create flags using proc sql -I will need to do this for the other variables including sex, race, age, etc. What is the easiest way to create a flag and also show the counts of the variables? The end goal would be three columns the counts of the two gender variables and then a flag saying if there was an increase or decrease of 100 from the two weeks.

This is the code I have so far:

```
proc sql;

create table joined as

select coalesce(a.person_key, b.person_key) as person_key,

a.gender_old, b.gender_new,

a.sexor_old, b.sexor_new,

a.race_cd_old, b.race_cd_new,

a.age_group_old, b.age_group_new,

a.sex_old, b.sex_new,

a.peh1_old, b.peh1_new,

a.peh2_old, b.peh2_new,

a.dose_total_old, b.dose_total_new

from oldperson a

full join newperson b

on a.person_key = b.person_key;
```

quit;
/Goal: Flag significant increases and flag ANY drops./

Comment: Not sure I understand how a text variable like gender could have either an increase or a decrease.  If you want to create a variable that indicates whether the two values are equal just store the result of the comparison as a variable.  `... ,(a.sex=b.sex) as sex_flag ....`  TRUE will be represented by 1 and FALSE by 0.

Comment: If you make a schematic table of your expected results, it will help others to help you.

Comment: Do a Proc SUMMARY of the output of Proc COMPARE ... ; ID PERSON_KEY